# Where are the UART Rx and Tx pins on a dsPIC33FJ32MC202?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm a beginner to micro-controller and now learning Microchip's dsPIC. I'm trying to use UART with RS232 to communicate with my laptop, but I can't find out where the Rx and Tx pins are on the chip.

I've checked [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70283K.pdf) and I can't find out where it has mentioned about which pin number it is.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to Keelan's answer:

The official name for the technology is "peripheral pin select" or PPS.

[image]

The 4th column in table 1-1 is the PPS column. You can see that the UART pins are all listed as 'Yes' which tells you that you need to use PPS to get these functions physically connected to pins.

Table 4-16 lists the input register map: file RPINR18 concerns the UART receive function. The value you write to RPOR18's low byte will determine which pin acts as UART receive.

[image]

Table 10-2 lists the output registers for PPS. UART transmit is 0x03; you would write 0x03 to the RPOR register corresponding to your desired output pin to connect it to UART transmit.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're on the RPn pins:

> The RPn pins can be used by any remappable peripheral. See Table 1 for the list of available
>   peripherals.

You can select on which pin you want the U1TX and U1RX functions.